# Change default account in "Add new contact"

Tags: contacts, settings

I have several accounts on my phone. When I add a new contact, my Google/Gmail account is always preselected, but I always want to add my contacts to another one, and quite often I forget to change the account.

**Is it possible to change the default account so I don't need to switch account every time I add a new contact?**

Phone: Lenovo Moto G4 Plus with Android 7.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure but perhaps it would be help be for you go to **Settings->Accounts->Google->(turn off) contacts.**

Comment: It's something different to turn off a contact storage or to change the default, so that's unlikely to be the answer. Apart from which: doesn't this only turn off synchronization?

Comment: After that you can turn on contacts storage into another contact.

Comment: So with a few more words, what you suggest is: first turn off Google contacts storage, then add a new contact (should ask again for "default storage"), then turn Google contacts back on? Have you tried that? While it sounds reasonable, the place you describe IMHO just toggles sync.